# objective-c multiple popoverviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have multiple popovercontroller in a UIView.
I am able  to call popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method for one popover but unable to do the same for all the popovercontrollers.

Can anybody suggest me, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you're able to call? Did you subclass UIPopoverController, and call the method yourself?

If you mean "it isn't called when my popovers are dismissed", we need more information. This is specified behavior in some circumstances. Let me quote from the docs:

> The popover controller does not call this method in response to programmatic calls to the `dismissPopoverAnimated:` method. If you dismiss the popover programmatically, you should perform any cleanup actions immediately after calling the `dismissPopoverAnimated:` method.

If you have multiple popovers and want to know which one has just been dismissed, you'll have to do a comparison in the method itself.

EDIT based on your comment:

The method is *always* called `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController`. This method is triggered by *any* popover that is dismissed by the user. If you have two different popovers that need different finalization, you have to differentiate between them within this method. This is why it has the parameter, in which the popovers put `self`, a pointer to themselves.

Your method should look like this:

```
popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    if (popoverController == myFirstPopoverController)
    {
        //do something
    }

    if (popoverController == mySecondPopoverController)
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two instance (firstPopover and secondpopover) of PopoverViewController. I need to perform some actions when the firstPopover and secondpopover are dismissed. If I have created popover named instance of PopoverViewController then -(void)popoverControllerDidDismissController works but when I write -(void)firstPopoverControllerDidDismissController does not work.

Comment: I tried with ur suggested code but control is not at all coming to the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method.

Comment: I am performing NSLOG(@"First Popover Dismissed") NSLOG(@"Second Popover Dismissed")NSLOG(@"Third Popover Dismissed") when popover gets dismissed

Comment: @krishna Have you set your viewController as the delegate of the popovers?

Comment: @krishna Then I'm not sure what's wrong, and can't tell without more code. Each instance of UIPopoverController calls this method of its delegate when it was dismissed by the user (but not when it was dismissed programmatically).